# Overriding vs Data Fields - which is the better option?

Tags: java, oop

For example, a custom component needs to know what String to paint as its title.

**Overriding**

```
CustomComponent c = new CustomComponent(){
    @Override
    public String getTitle(){
        return "A given title";
    }
};
```

**Fields**

```
CustomComponent c = new CustomComponent()
c.setTitle("A given title");
```

Using the first method, I don't need to create a String field in CustomComponent, but the code is much cleaner. Is there a strongly preferred / suggested way, and if so why? 
Note that this is just a simple example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all CustomComponents have a simple string title then a data field is the way to go.

Move to a method once things become a bit more complicated (e.g. the title needs subclass specific info [like how many children it "owns"]).